# Angular $watch input email

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently trying to write a directive to handle form input errors.
So far it looks like this:

```
directive('input', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            var name = attrs.name;
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                console.log(name + ' changed');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And in the html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.text">
```

This way I'm able to check any form error in the $watch callback.

However, it does not work with `input[type="email"]` that have a `required` attribute, and cannot figure out why the `$watch` callback is not fired in that case.

Here is an example to illustrate this with different input components: http://jsfiddle.net/g0atq0z4/

Any idea how to detect when the ngModel changes in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it trigger the event after the the arroba, try "abc@"

Also you should use ng-change if you want to detect any change to the input

As this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p0qo4qst/

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.changed = function (){
        console.log('changed');
    };

});
```

Also, you may use inputs inside a **form** which will provide you the $dirty, $valid and $invalid states.

read more at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

> $dirty boolean     True if user has already interacted with the form.
>
> $valid boolean     True if all of the containing forms and controls are
>   valid.
>
> $invalid - boolean     True if at least one containing control or form is
>   invalid.